# pass paramters in net.Socket.connect

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript and NodeJS, came from C++ background.

TCP client connect is working fine and connected successfully to `nc -l 5010` with following code

```
function connect(p_port, p_ip) {
  client.connect(5010, '0.0.0.0', function() {
...
});
}
```

but not with following code

```
var v_port = 5010;
var v_ip = '0.0.0.0';

function connect(p_port=v_port, p_ip=v_ip) {
  client.connect(p_port, p_ip, function() {
...
});
}
```

what I am doing wrong regarding passing arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 hours of debugging found that,
`p_ip` parameter name was conflicting with other variable.